# Creating a ssis package using sql server data tools

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, ssms, sql-server-data-tools

I am new to ssis.I have a task where i need to import data from table to excel and table contains nearly 500K records.My problem is when opt for excel file destination and create a connection manager and use excel 2007 then i cannot see tables under name of excel sheet.when i tried to install access database engine
i struck with error saying you cannot install 32 bit because you have installed 64 bit of Microsoft products.Please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link to your access database engine driver. You can choose 32bit and 64bit. Remember to reboot.

[Microsoft Excel ACE Driver](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

You could also choose a flatfile destination as CSV instead, and then load that in Excel. That is easier imo.